# How to compile rego file into WASM using Java?

Tags: java, compilation, webassembly, opa, rego

Is there a way to compile the rego file used by OPA into WASM using Java?

Currently I'm using the following command to compile a rego policy into WASM and bundling it with data into a gz file

```bash
./opa build -t wasm -o ../out/bundle.tar.gz -e example/allowed policy.rego data.json
```

I'm using kawamuray library to evaluate the policies contained in wasm file.

```
// This is the relevant code..
// I  want to pass the rego policy file name in place of gzBundleName
// then compile it into wasm and carry on the rest of program as such

public static void executePolicy(String gzBundleName, String user) {
    try {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Bundle bundle = BundleUtil.extractBundle(gzBundleName);

        try (OPAModule om = new OPAModule(bundle)) {
            String valueString = om.evaluate(user, entry_point);

            JsonNode _evaluation = objectMapper.readTree(valueString);

            logger.info("evaluation result :"+ _evaluation.get(0).get("result"));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("failure", e);
    }
}
```